# Is this method of coding exploitable?

Tags: ios, security, api-key, secret-key

I'm new to app development and am currently developing an ios app using swift in xcode. During the app development process, it's been brought to my attention that I shouldn't store sensitive information such as API secrets as local variables. I'm assuming this is because there are methods of viewing an app's code.

The app I'm developing has no accounts or user log-in, and I don't want it to. For simplicity, I'll explain it this way:

A user may make a "room" with a certain room ID specified by that user. The user's device has an associated ID that is saved to a database to show that the created room is owned by that user.

Another user, specified as a guest, may join said room with said room ID. When they attempt to join the room, their device ID is checked against the database, and a local Boolean is specified stating whether or not this user is the host.

Whether or not the user is the host, a segue commences to another view controller, and the Boolean is sent too. From this point on there are functions and statements that only get called if the Boolean specifies that the user is the host, allowing only hosts certain permissions.

My worry is that there is some way to exploit this such that guests may somehow change or set that local Boolean to signify that they are the host when they are not. Should I worry about this as a potential security issue? No personal information of hosts or guests is saved or used in this app outside of device-specific IDs, which are saved in or checked against the database, but I would still like the security of only allowing hosts specific room permissions.

Comment: _The user's device has an associated ID that is saved to a database_ You mean a **remote** database right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm assuming this is because there are methods of viewing an app's code.

Not precisely, but it's best if you assume this is true. Your exact source code is not available, but any data stored in the app can be extracted, and any algorithm the app implements can be reverse engineered. You cannot hide anything in an app you ship to a user.

> My worry is that there is some way to exploit this such that guests may somehow change or set that local Boolean to signify that they are the host when they are not.

This is true, but isn't really the main security concern. The fundamental concern is that the server can never trust an app. I am free to create my own app that connects to your server and sends whatever I want. The server must be resilient to that. So things like "room owner" checks must be performed on the server. You cannot rely on the app performing them. You have to assume the app is under the complete control of its user. Given that, what security issues do you see?

Comment: Well, I'm currently using the Firebase realtime database. Does what you said mean I'd have to use one of their user-authentication methods?

Comment: Certainly. But also remember that any permissions you configure can be used by directly contacting Firebase. So if you allow a user to modify another user's data, I don't have to use the app to do that. I could connect directly to Firebase and perform any action you've allowed the account.

Comment: You can create auto-generated usernames and passwords (or tokens) on the device to protect users from each other without requiring users to create passwords, but that won't prevent the user from using the *own* credentials to do anything the database allows.

Comment: I apologize if I'm eating up your time, but I don't think I quite understand what to do yet. I really appreciate your help so far, but please don't be bothered to continue helping if I ask too much. With that said, let's say there is an associated list of stuff in a room. The host may delete anything from that list, but guests may only delete what they add. Are you suggesting this deletion of stuff from the list in the database be Firebase-side? Are you referencing cloud functions? Is there a way I can query Firebase for authorization and execute database changes app-side?

Comment: It's no problem. My point is that the only thing that can enforce "only owners can delete things" is a server. The app cannot enforce that. Generally it is difficult to implement this kind of system if the app directly connects to the database. Usually you have a server (or lambdas) in the middle that provides an API and enforces the rules. When connecting to your API, you'll provide authentication, and the API will determine if what you're requesting is allowed.

Comment: Personally I do this kind of work on AWS, so I'd probably build a simple API with API Gateway, wire it to some Lambda functions, and store the data in DynamoDB. The DynamoDB would not be directly available to the outside world. Personally I avoid Firebase; I find it very over-complicated and tricky to configure, particularly if you want anything that isn't "let Google track every single thing your customers do." (But many people use FB very successfully; I'm just not a fan.)